# Structure theorem for etale maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

I have been trying to understand the structure theorem for etale maps for rings. Let $A\to B$ be a local homomorphism of Noetherian local rings which is etale. Then the structure theorem says that $B=A[T]_g/p(T)$, where $g\in A[T]$ is such that $p'(T)$ is a unit in $B$.

This theorem is given as Theorem 3.14 in Milne's book on etale cohomology. The way the proof proceeds, it seems that the degree of the polynomial $p$ is equal to field extension degree $[k(y):k(x)]$, where $y$ denotes the maximal ideal of $B$ and $x$ denotes the maximal ideal of $A$. This seems to be wrong since if we take $A$ and $B$ to be localizations of finitely generated algebras over an algebraically closed field, then this extension degree will always be 1, which would mean that $B$ is isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: A[T]/p(T) is an extension of A and inverting g has the effect of removing possibly ramified primes from the picture. 

Comment: I haven't checked the notes, but an etale morphism should induce a map $i : k(x) \rightarrow k(y)$. The degree (I believe) should be $[k(y) : i(k(x))]$. This need not be one (as the map $\mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ sending $x \rightarrow x^n$ shows).

Comment: Generally $A[T]_g/(p)$ is *not* local, and likewise an essentially finite type local map between local noetherian rings is virtually never finite type and hence cannot be etale. The correct statement is that if $A \rightarrow B$ is etale then after suitable *Zariski-localization* on both $A$ and $B$ (around any chosen point in Spec($B$) and its image in Spec($A$)) we reach the you describe with $p$ also *monic*. Typically $p$ has *reducible* specialization at points of Spec($A$), and its degree is controlled by the fiber degrees over Spec($A$), not by residual degrees on Spec($B$).

Comment: @pranavk : If $A$ is local, then $A[T]_g/p(T)$ can be local for the following reason. If $A$ is local, then $A[T]/p(T)$ is semi local and then if we invert an element which is contained in all but one of the maximal ideals, then $A[T]_g/p(T)$ is local.

Comment: @rghthndsd : If $k(x)$ is algebraically closed, then the degree will be 1. Even for the map $\mathbb{A}^1\to \mathbb{A}^1$, if the underlying field is algebraically closed, then the map at the level of residue fields has degree 1. 

Comment: The degree is not $[k(y):k(x)]$ but the dimension of the affine ring of $f^{-1}(x)$ over $k(x)$.

Comment: @Rex: Yes, I know that locality *can* happen; what I wrote is that *generally* (meaning "in some cases" -- in fact most cases in some sense) it does not happen.  Moreover, since local maps essentially of finite type between local noetherian rings are virtually never finite type, you have to give up locality on $B$ if you want to formulate the structure theorem in the satisfactory way that is done in EGA.

Answer (score 2):

The degree is $1$ when $A,B$ *are* finitely generated algebras over an algebraically closed field, yes, but then they are not local (unless they are artinian), and the degree can be arbitrary if $A,B$ are just localizations of finitely generated algebras. Already the "trivial" direction of the classification of étale morphisms shows that your argument is not correct, every degree is possible.

Comment: Let $E\to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a degree 2 map over the complex numbers. Let $y\in E$ be a closed point which is unramified and let $x$ be the image of $y$. Then I would have thought that the ring homomorphism $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1,x}\to \mathscr{O}_{E,y}$ is etale. Both the local rings have residue field $\mathbb{C}$ and so the degree of the extension is 1, but clearly they are not isomorphic.

Comment: @Rex: In your example, the ring homomorphism between the stalks is étale, but it is not finite. (The homomorphism from $\mathscr O_{\mathbb P^1, x}$ to the semi-local ring whose maximal ideals correspond to the two points in $E$ lying over $y$ is finite, but to get rid of the second point you need to localize.)